# How is my book doing what it's doing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, work

[image: This]

This is the stem. I'm concerned with the answer to d. First of all, the book doesn't specify what the two processes are, but I think the first process is, lifting each cube individually and stacking them on top of each other, and the second process is gluing the 5 cubes together and then lifting the column from the ground by rotating the column 90 degrees.

d asks us, which process is more effective. In both cases, the work done will be equal. So, what they mean is, which process requires less average force.

[image: Soln]

This is the solution. In both cases, the work done is 1225 joules. I understand that part. However, I really don't get how they found the average force in the first and second processes. Is their methodology correct?

This is not a homework question. This is not a check my work question either; I'm not asking anyone to check my work, rather I'm asking if the authors of the book applied the concepts of physics correctly in their calculations.

Comment: What's "functional force" in the second picture?

Comment: I think they mean net force as $mg\sin\theta$ is canceled by the normal force from the ground, and $mg\cos\theta$ is the only force that remains.

Comment: Do you have a doubt in how they found the average value of the forces, or why they did it? Have you tried finding the total force applied to obtain the two structures? I think that would be effective too if you were trying to find which one is "easier".

Comment: @AbuSafwan I suggest you edit your question to make it clear that you are asking about the application of the underlying concepts of force and work, and not asking anyone to double-check the calculation in the solution.

Comment: @AbuSafwan, This is a question about a very specific computation that is unlikely to be useful to the community at large. That's why it's been closed. Whether the computation is yours or someone else's is not pertinent.

Comment: I suggest completely scrapping the text book and just asking your conceptual question. Using your answer you can then discern for yourself if the book is right or not.

Answer (score 1):

The given solution to part (d) is nonsense and shows a misunderstanding of the relationship between work and force.

You can make the average force needed to lift the blocks as small as you like by using a  [simple machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_machine) with a suitably high mechanical advantage. A ramp or pulley system would be good when raising the blocks individually. To lift the column of blocks in one piece, increase the length of your lever arm using an A-frame. If you insist on pushing the column from below (as the answer seems to suggest) then push at the far end, not the middle of the column - that immediately halves the average force.

So (ignoring friction) the average force needed can be as small as you like, work done is the same (since a smaller force has to be applied over a longer distance), and neither way of stacking the blocks is inherently more effective than the other.

Comment: Is the average force calculated by the authors to rotate the column of cubes correct?

Comment: @AbuSafwan The average force needed depends on how and where the force is applied. I think the book is assuming a force of $5mg\cos \theta$ is applied at the centre of the column. But common sense tells us it requires less force to lift the far end of the column - then the average force required is half of the book’s value.

Comment: We don't seem to have the complete question. From the information given, I think the answer to part (a) is "Thursday".  Prove me wrong!